Unable to use fastai load_learner() within Flask app
I'm getting this error when using the load_learner() in an api call
Custom classes or functions exported with your `Learner` not available in namespace.\\Re-declare/import before loading:\n\tCan't get attribute 'label_func' on <module '__main__' from '/home/user/USER/venv/bin/gunicorn'>

I'm confused as to why I need a label_func() in the first place even if I'm not using it, but I went ahead and added one that won't fail.
Here is my code with a label_func in both place just in case.
Additionally, after checking this file is indeed _main_
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import os
from fastai.vision.all import *

from src.classifier import Classifier

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

def label_func(f):
    return "test"


class ClassifySceenshot(Resource):
    def label_func(f):
        return "test"
    
    def get(self):
        filename = "tmp_0.jpg"
        try:
            c = Classifier()
            c.save_capture(filename)
            with open(filename, "rb") as img:
                image = img.read()
            bytes_array = bytearray(image)
            prediction, pred_idx, probability = load_learner("testing.pkl").predict(bytes_array)
            os.remove(filename)
            return {'status': 'success',
                    'prediction': prediction,
                    'probability': probability[pred_idx],
                    }, 200
        except Exception as e:
            os.remove(filename)
            return {'status': 'error', 'message': str(e)}, 500


api.add_resource(ClassifySceenshot, '/classify')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=XXXX, debug=True)

This is load_learner from learner.py in fastai:
def load_learner(fname, cpu=True, pickle_module=pickle):
    "Load a `Learner` object in `fname`, by default putting it on the `cpu`"
    distrib_barrier()
    map_loc = 'cpu' if cpu else default_device()
    try: res = torch.load(fname, map_location=map_loc, pickle_module=pickle_module)
    except AttributeError as e: 
        e.args = [f"Custom classes or functions exported with your `Learner` not available in namespace.\Re-declare/import before loading:\n\t{e.args[0]}"]
        raise
    if cpu: 
        res.dls.cpu()
        if hasattr(res, 'channels_last'): res = res.to_contiguous(to_fp32=True)
        elif hasattr(res, 'mixed_precision'): res = res.to_fp32()
        elif hasattr(res, 'non_native_mixed_precision'): res = res.to_non_native_fp32()
    return res


Can you provide a MRE for your question? The code snippet is incomplete to allow for easy repIication.

why did you tag this as "opencv"? there is no relation at all to opencv.

@etch_45 I went ahead and added the whole load_learner function. It's within the fastai library

@ChristophRackwitz hmm I don't have the opencv tag on there... but I am using opencv within this project

you did have the opencv tag on this question. I removed it. don't you remember that you put it there? it's all in the immutable history: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78344335/1

Oh I see now. It is because my save_capure function uses cv2.VideoCapture. Thanks for editing it tho
